# Jquery Image Crop to a dynamic shape

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wish to have an interface that can achieve something similar to the screen shot attached.
Is this possible in Javascript - interested to here of Jquery examples.

[Screenshot http://ploader.net/files/a612027c553e7445b8fed99c4891aa11.png](http://ploader.net/files/a612027c553e7445b8fed99c4891aa11.png)

Comment: You can create a path with `<canvas>` and draw the image with that path. I'm not sure of complete interfaces.

Comment: you can get the coordinates to crop with javascript, but the croping will be done in the serverside

Comment: You might be able to do that client-side on a canvas, not without it though, unless you use an alternate technology like Flash, Java or Silverlight.  Mostly that would be done server-side where needed, though that looks like you want control points on the screen possibly with live dragging.

Comment: Thanks guys - the use of Canvas at the moment is not an option, just down to browser compatability. Looks like Flash wins this battle then :)